# Select MAX value inside a JOIN and JOIN inside another SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

table a:

```
PersonID | name | age | gender  
-------- | ---- | --- | ------  
20       | John | 45  | Male  
30       | Ann  | 50  | Female
```

table b:

```
ValueID | PersonID | Column1   
------- | -------- | -------  
1       | 20       | 654321  
2       | 20       | 345653  
3       | 30       | 756756  
4       | 30       | 142857
```

I need to get all values from table 'a' and for each one a corresponding Column1 with a.PersonID = b.PersonID and with the MAX ValueID.

The expected result in this example would be the following:

```
 PersonID | name | age | gender | Column1
 -------- | ---- | --- | ------   -------
 20       | John | 45  | Male   | 345653  
 30       | Ann  | 50  | Female | 142857
```

I tried this and doesn't work.

```
SELECT ps.*, 
(SELECT Column1 FROM b ef  
JOIN (SELECT MAX(ValueID) AS id FROM b  
  WHERE PersonID = ps.PersonID) max ON ef.PersonID = max.id ) AS Column1  
FROM a ps
```

I guess `ps.PersonID` in WHERE clause `ef.PersonID = ps.PersonID` is not recognized.

I appreciate very much your help.

Comment: @strawberry... not a full duplicate... different issue here

Comment: @mastashufu not if your answer is anything to go by

Comment: @Strawberry simple english please.. as far as i know it should fix the issue

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see this is duplicated. PersonID and ValueID are unique. I cannot GROUP BY any of them. I haven't been able to find a solution yet. Thanks for your help

Comment: Looks like an exact duplicate to me `SELECT a.*,x.valueid,x.column1 FROM tablea a JOIN tableb x.* ON x.personid = a.personid JOIN ( SELECT personid , MAX(valueid) valueid FROM tableb GROUP BY personid ) y ON y.personid = x.personid AND y.valueid = x.valueid`

Answer (score 0):

Try This.. presumably the valueid is unique/ identity seeded

```
SELECT ps.*, 
(SELECT Column1 FROM b 
where b.valueId =(SELECT MAX(ValueID) FROM b as x
  WHERE x.PersonID = ps.PersonID)
) AS Column1  
FROM a ps
```

Comment: mysql keeps saying: " Unknown column 'ps.PersonID' in 'where clause' "

Comment: can you post your query here

Comment: My query is the one I posted before. My real query is exactly, just changes the names of the fields. I have edited and now is correct. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT ps.*, 
  (SELECT Column1 
   FROM b ef  
   JOIN (SELECT MAX(ValueID) AS id FROM b  
   WHERE PersonID = ps.PersonID) max ON ef.PersonID = max.id ) AS Column1  
FROM a ps
```

Comment: max is based on the column valueid to get the column1 value

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now.

Comment: That's right @maSTAShuFu